# javascript FileReader freezes browser when reading file over 500kb

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use FileReader after user uploads pictures so that the user can preview his/her images. It works smoothly if the picture's size is about 100kb, however, when it is above 500kb, the browser will freeze for seconds. Once I upload a 2MB picture and it took the browser 1 min to load.so my question is how to make it work fast in background? or is there a way to compress the picture using javascript or jQuery before it is processed by FileReader?

```
function read_img(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            for(i=0;i<$(input.files).length;i++) {
                (function(file) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $(".preview").append("<img src='"+e.target.result+"'/>")
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                })(input.files[i]);
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Browser will freeze when you overload the javascript engine. I am afraid there is no way to do this without browser freezing. You should try alternative approaches.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this without the browser "freezing".  Please show your code so we can help you further.

Comment: If you are reading a lot of files at once, this may be your issue.  In that case, simply queue the read attempts so only n attempts occur simultaneously.   If you are noticing browser issues when only reading one small file, then there are either issues with your browser or there is some other code causing this problem.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the code. Is that before you upload the image or after? Does this code run in the client or the server? Why aren't you using a `file://` URL to display the image?

Comment: @AaronDigulla Uploading isn't involved here.  The OP is confusing his/her words.  The OP is generating client-side image previews.  The code above executes in the browser, and there is no URL for the image.  The OP is taking a `File` provided by the browser's File API that represents a user-selected image file and generating a data URL, which is used to display the image in an `<img>`.

Comment: @RayNicholus: Thanks. OP said, the lock happened with a single 2MB image. I'm wondering what could be causing problems there. The 3MB base64 encoded String shouldn't be a big issue :-7

Comment: @RayNicholus you are probably right, after I switch to test it in chrome this problem is gone. are you aware of any compatibility issue of this api with safari?

Comment: Not really.  What version of Safari, and on which operating system?

Comment: No issues that i am aware of.

Comment: @Jz1012: Do you have an anti-virus installed? Maybe it wants to check the data and gets confused? Use a system monitor and the browser's performance tools to see where all the time goes.